# Which approach to write logic in redux is more correct/convenient?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

For example, if in some situation I need to update the state in the reduсer 'x', 'y', 'z'. This can be done by creating thunk, and from it to call something like :

```
dispatch(xUpdated('x'))
dispatch(yUpdated('y'))
dispatch(zUpdated('z'))
```

Or you can assign a single action `(xyzUpdated({x, y, z}))` and subscribe to it in each of the reducers.
In what situations, which approach may be more convenient? And what options are more often used in practice?

Answer (score 1):

**I suggest working backward from the reducers you need based on your business logic.**

If there are n cases needed in the reducer then you should plan to have n action creators and consequently you will call dispatch n number of times with each one of your action creators like so

```
//Reducer 
    switch (action.type) {
        case ACTION_TYPE_1:
         break;
        case ACTION_TYPE_2:
         break;
    .... case ACTION_TYPE_n:
         break;

//Action creator 
    export const action1 = (x1) => {
      return { type: ACTION_TYPE_1, payload: x1 //specific to ACTION_TYPE_1 };
    };
    ...
    export const actionN = (xN) => {
      return { type: ACTION_TYPE_1, payload: xN //specific to ACTION_TYPE_N };
    };

//Calling dispatch
    dispatch(actionN(x1));
    ...
    dispatch(actionN(xN));
```

Now, let's say you need 3 reducers->actions->dispatch and you want to club them into one that would mean

- A more complex reducer and action creator function which affects the code **readability**. Typically you want your code to be easily understood by other engineers.
- The second issue is **over-fetching** of data since you are passing unnecessary data on every dispatch. Now, this is not a performance issue but just good practice not to pass unnecessary data to and fro Redux or other state management tools.

In the end, I would prioritize readability and clean function over reducing the number of lines in a code. So, you should have as many dispatch calls that make sense from a business logic point of view and then avoid clubbing them together.

Happy coding!